# Nested fragment references in Thymeleaf not work as expected

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm stumbling on a silly problem which is causing me headaches since this morning; hope you guys could help me understand where I'm failing.

I'm currently developing a simple app using Springboot + Thymeleaf + bootstrap 5; I'll try to explain briefly my problem, the relevant code will be latter in the page.

Let's say I have a "components" file which contains a lot of sections marked with `th:fragment`, inside one of these sections I'm trying to `th:replace` a `div` that is located inside another "components" file and this section accept a parameter which is another fragment that should be rendered inside the second component.

The code is messy as my description and I'm clearly missing a focal point, but bear with me and my messy code:

**components/coltivazione_template.html**

```
...
<div th:fragment="simple-button-modal" class="my-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Add</button>
    <th:block th:insert="~{components/common-components :: form-modal(template='components/coltivazione_template :: coltivazione-upsert-form')}" />
</div>
...
<div th:fragment="coltivazione-upsert-form">
    <p>Sample text</p>
</div>
...
```

**components/commons_template.html**

```
...
<div th:fragment="form-modal(template)" class="modal fade" id="thisModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Stocazz</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div th:replace="${template}"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

If I directly `th:replace="~{components/coltivazione_template :: coltivazione-upsert-form}"` it works as expected but if I try the way I showed you before, I get:
*"Error resolving template [components/coltivazione_template :: coltivazione-upsert-form], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"*

Hope it's clear enough to get you an idea and, possibly, an hint or a solution :).

Many thanks in advance for your precious help!

***EDIT***
Right after I wrote this post I tried another approach that seems to correctly render the nested fragment:

**components/coltivazione_template.html**

```
...
<div th:fragment="simple-button-modal" class="my-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Add</button>
    <th:block th:insert="~{components/common-components :: form-modal(template=~{components/coltivazione_template :: coltivazione-upsert-form})}" />
</div>
...
<div th:fragment="coltivazione-upsert-form">
    <p>Sample text</p>
</div>
...
```

before:
`<th:block th:insert="~{components/common-components :: form-modal(template='components/coltivazione_template :: coltivazione-upsert-form')}" />` 
after:
`<th:block th:insert="~{components/common-components :: form-modal(template=~{components/coltivazione_template :: coltivazione-upsert-form})}" />`

The remaining part is the same as before. 
Is this the right approach?

Thanks for your time!